# CA Real ID Expiration Date

Tags: usa, student-visa, driving-license, identification, california

I recently applied for my DL and my California state ID card. I chose my California State ID card to be made Real. Also, my Cal State ID arrived before my DL.

Both my Cal State ID and DL expire on 03/14/2021. My I-20 expires on 05/14/2021.

Some of my friends who are on an F1 visa have their DL valid until their F1 visa expires, and not the I-20. (No idea why? I think their ID's aren't REAL)

My question is if my DL expires on 03/14/2021 and if I would not have received my OPT yet, is there any way I could renew it?

If not, could I renew it after my OPT arrives, without giving another Behind-the-wheel driving test?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. However, the DMV website here: dmv.ca.gov/portal/driver-licenses-identification-cards/… provides for online renewal of Real ID Driver's Licenses, provided your information (address etc) hasn't changed. If your information hasn't changed, and as you will still be in status on your I-20 in early 2021, I suspect that you'll be able to renew your Real ID Driver's License (and your California Real ID card) online (that is, no driving test) before the two cards expire.

Comment: Even if you have to renew it in person, you won't have to take the written nor the driving test again. They might make you take the vision test though.